# How can I allow a user to create different types of objects, in order to use Java polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, object, inheritance, polymorphism

I am currently taking lessons in OOP java. In my code below i am implementing polymorphism at run time as well as inheritance. I am creating a constant named "balance".
The goal of this program is to create a class called Account and extend the class with two types of classes called SBaccount and current.

The common attributes shared with Account is name, number and amount. So far i have a working code but its not quite doing what I want yet.
I want to be able to ask the user for the type of account that needs to be created, once the user specifies the type I want to validate the user input. I also want for example if a user deposits xx amount, that amount should be added to the balance and then stored. I want in the "withdraw" method, when the user makes a withdrawal it should be taken from the balance.

My code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    abstract class Account{
    String number;
    String name;
    int amount;
    static final int balance = 1000; 
    int bal;
    
    public  Account(){
        
        
    }
    
    int deposit(int i) {
        return i;
    
    }
    
    void withdrawal(int i){
    
    }
    
    
}

   final class sbaccount extends Account {
    
    
    public sbaccount() {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    int deposit (int money){
        bal = money + balance;
        
        System.out.println("You have deposited :$"+money );
        System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :"+bal);
        return bal;
    }
        void withdrawal(int withdraw){
        
        if (bal <= balance){
            System.out.println("Your balance is too low for withdrawal!");
        
        }
        else{
            
            amount = bal - withdraw;
            System.out.println("You have withdrawn :$"+ withdraw);
            System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :"+ amount);
        }
        
      }
    
}
  final class current extends Account {

    
    public current() {
        
    }
    
    int deposit ( int money){
        bal = money + balance;
        
        System.out.println("You have deposited :$"+money);
        System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :"+ bal);
        return bal;
    
    }
    void withdrawal(int withdraw){
        
        if (bal <= balance){
            System.out.println("Your balance is too low for withdrawal!");
        
        }
        else{
            
            amount = bal - withdraw;
            System.out.println("You have withdrawn :$"+ withdraw);
            System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :"+ amount);
        }
        
      }
     
    
    
}
   public class oopassignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String type;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What type of account do you want to create? :");
        type=input.nextLine();
        
        Account sb;
        sb = new sbaccount();
        sb.deposit(500);
        sb.withdrawal(100);
        sb = new current();
        sb.deposit(500000);
        sb.withdrawal(1000000);
        
        

      }
   }
```

Comment: What's "polymerization"? Do you mean *polymorphism*?

Comment: yes i mean polymorphism** at runtime, sorry about that

Comment: Just FYI, you should properly format your uploaded code. Also, this isn't really an OOP question so you should adjust your tags and title. What you seem to want is a method of storing user input.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm new to Stack so I'm currently just getting a hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

**So you can do the following task through class.newInstance() method.**

```
System.out.println("What type of account do you want to create? :");
String account_type = input.next();
Class c = Class.forName(account_type);
Account sb = (Account)c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

The class c will load the class according to the argument passed. And object will be created through casting (required as initially the the object is of type "Class").

**So finally your code will be (some modification is done) :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Account {
    String number;
    String name;
    int amount;
    static final int balance = 1000;
    int bal;

    abstract int deposit(int i);

    abstract void withdrawal(int i);

}

final class sbaccount extends Account {

    int deposit(int money) {
        bal = money + balance;

        System.out.println("You have deposited :$" + money);
        System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :" + bal);
        return bal;
    }

    void withdrawal(int withdraw) {

        if (bal <= balance) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is too low for withdrawal!");

        } else {
            amount = bal - withdraw;
            System.out.println("You have withdrawn :$" + withdraw);
            System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :" + amount);
        }

    }

}

final class current extends Account {

    int deposit(int money) {
        bal = money + balance;

        System.out.println("You have deposited :$" + money);
        System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :" + bal);
        return bal;

    }

    void withdrawal(int withdraw) {

        if (bal <= balance) {
            System.out.println("Your balance is too low for withdrawal!");

        } else {

            amount = bal - withdraw;
            System.out.println("You have withdrawn :$" + withdraw);
            System.out.println("Your Account balance is now :" + amount);
        }

    }
}

public class oopassignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What type of account do you want to create? :");
        String account_type = input.next();
        // The only valid optios are : sbaccount & current.
        // If any other class name is inputted. It will show exception
        Class c = Class.forName(account_type);
        Account sb = (Account)c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        sb.deposit(500);
        sb.withdrawal(100);
        sb = new current();
        sb.deposit(500000);
        sb.withdrawal(1000000);
    }
}
```

Let me know if any modification is needed to answer.